# Where is the algorithm that determines how many points a set of characters in a certain font and size takes up?

Tags: python, fonts

Suppose you have the Gettysburg Address and you want to write an algorithm such that you don't have a doc where 44 lines are on one page and 1 line is on another page and that is it.  You want to make it so that 30 lines are on one page and 15 are on the other. If you're trying to figure out how many a text takes up which does not have the \n character but is just one long string it's not very easy.  If you know that your document is 4 inches wide, and you know that if the text is center justified and you know the text is in 12 point Times New Roman font then there should be an algorithm that computes how many lines that would take up.  I'm using Python so it would be great if I could find such an algorithm in Python.

Let me give an example.

Suppose your string is:

```
str1 = 'Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation or any nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle-field of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this.'
```

In Python you can't figure how many lines that will take up on the page.  It depends on the font size, the font and the width of the page.  Well, if you know that the width of the page is, say, 1000 points and you know that TimesNewRoman size 12 will take 2300 points, then you can conclude that that text will take up 3 lines.  I need a function of the form:

```
def get_points(str1="",font=TimesNewRoman,size=12)
   return points
```

Where you input the string, the font and the size and it will output the number of points.  It would also help if I could convert inches to points in a document.

Comment: Please explain your question. I find it impossible to answer right now, as it is not clear to me what you are actually asking. Provide input and output.

Comment: You have to get that information from the API that is going to render the text. How that is done varies wildly by library: `pygame` does it one way, Windows does it another, `reportlab` yet another. But in broad outline they work similarly. You create a canvas or equivalent, put your text on the canvas, then ask the API for the resulting dimensions.

Comment: I'm doing it in Rich Text Format.  I can't even figure out what keywords to enter to do a google search.  If put 'points' in my Google search then I keep getting stuff about games.  I get a lot of sites that think I just want to figure out how to write lines of code.